# How do I hide scrollbar in webkit browser?

Tags: css, webkit, scrollbar, custom-scrolling

http://jsfiddle.net/mWpLC/

Please, check link.
When you press mouse over the text, then drag cursor to right - browser scroll appeared.

How to fix this for webkit browser? Text must be scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this overflow-y:scroll;

```
.custom-scroll__scroll-area {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll; /*Remove This Line*/
    position: relative;
    right: -16px;
}
```

Comment: Text must be scrollable, without this line scroll didn't working.